# pip wants to uninstall site-packages from a different virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm working in a python virtual environment (with `virtualenvwrapper`).
I created a branch of my code and I wanted to edit it in a different virtualenv. I define the path to my django src folder (and a few more things) in the postactivate script.

I did `$ cpvirtualenv ~/.virtualenv/v1 ~/.virtualenv/v2`
it was copied successfully.

I then `workon v2` and wanted to `pip uninstall PIL`. I get the following error:

```
Not uninstalling PIL at /home/myuser/.virtualenv/v1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL, outside environment /home/myuser/.virtualenv/v2
```

I also tried it from `~/.virtualenv/v2`

I don't want to uninstall PIL from v1, but from v2. I also tried virtualenv-clone and I don't get what's happening.
I can always create a new virtualenv, copy the postactivate script and `pip -r install requirements.txt` but I'd like to understand the error I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from the doc:

> Copying virtual environments is not well supported. Each virtualenv has path information hard-coded into it, and there may be cases where the copy code does not know to update a particular file. Use with caution.

Comment: agree. You should install from `requirements.txt` each time you create new env instead of copying it.

Comment: I see! thanks. I ended up doing it with requirements.txt this morning anyway.